# Properly removing event handler after component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am trying to implement an HOC which will unmount a component if user clicks outside. Here is my HOC `ClickOutsideHOC.js`

```
import React from 'react'

const ClickOutsideHOC = props => {

const {
    callback,
    identifier
} = props

React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleDOMClickHOC(identifier, callback))
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleDOMClickHOC) //  this needs repair
}, [])

    return props.children
}

const handleDOMClickHOC = (identifier, callback) => event => {
    const elem = document.querySelector(identifier)
    if (elem && !elem.contains(event.target))
        callback(false)
}
export default ClickOutsideHOC`
```

This is how I am using the HOC. `SomeOtherComponent.js`

```
const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = React.useState(false)
//
//
//
{
    toggleValue ? 
    <ClickOutsideHOC
        identifier=".some-class-name"
        callback={setToggleValue}
    >
        <div className="some-class-name">
        </div>
    </ClickOutsideHOC>: ''
}
```

This seems to be working. The problem is I am not sure about the procedure of removing event handler. The `handleDOMClickHOC` function is returning a new function reference which I am not storing anywhere. I think it will cause memory leak. I can see in the `Event Listeners` tab of chrome debugger console that multiple handlers are registered to DOM. How can I write this so that it ensures no memory leak due to unsubscribed event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you know that you need the reference to be able to remove a listener, why not to create it?

```js
import React from 'react'

const handleDOMClickHOC = (identifier, callback) => event => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(identifier)
  if (elem && !elem.contains(event.target))
    callback(false)
}

const ClickOutsideHOC = props => {

  const {
    callback,
    identifier
  } = props

  const listener = handleDOMClickHOC(identifier, callback);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', listener)
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', listener)
  }, [])

  return props.children
}
export default ClickOutsideHOC`
```

Comment: oh I see. let me check.

Comment: yeah it is working perfectly. I don't why it never occured to me to store the reference :p.

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind all necessary arguments with `call`:

In this way you'll always get the event, args and other stuff passed to Handler.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleDOMClickHOC.call(null, identifier, callback) } )
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleDOMClickHOC) //  this needs repair
}, [])
```

Comment: But `bind` creates a new function, so new reference

Comment: Using bind removes the need of currying but I think the problem remains

Comment: Yes you are right, so in that case call would work as it bind passes args with the function

Comment: So, in that case how the `event` object will get pass into the handler?

Comment: If you want pass event, add it as a second param after null

Comment: I don't think it will help. `handleDOMClickHOC.call` will return something which is different from `handleDOMClickHOC` itself, so you will not be able to remove that with `document.removeEventListener('click', handleDOMClickHOC)`